# How to produce lorentzian 2D sources in python

Tags: python, astropy

I am trying to produce 2D sources and add them to an image. Currently I'm generating gaussian sources through Gaussian2D (astropy):

```
min_x = int(rapix[i]) - 300
max_x = int(rapix[i]) + 300
min_y = int(decpix[i]) - 300
max_y = int(decpix[i]) + 300
y, x = np.mgrid[min_y:max_y, min_x:max_x] #HERE I CREATE THE GRID TO PUT THE SOURCES ON

fakesource = Gaussian2D(intensity, rapix[i], decpix[i], dimension, dimension)(x, y)
```

where the intensity and dimensions have been defined previously. I'd like to produce Lorentzian sources instead of Gaussians, but I did not find anything similar to Gaussian2D. Which is the best way to do it?

Comment: Since all you want is to sample points from a 2D Lorentzian (or, Cauchy) distributions, would  [scipy.stats.cauchy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.cauchy.html) satisfy you?

Comment: I don't think so; it just samples a value from a Cauchy distribution, while I'm trying to effectively produce a source whose points follow that distribution (so I need to specify the centre and its value, that are the peak of the 1D curve, but then all the other points must be drawn as a consequence).

Comment: I think I got it. Just a thing though: "[...] so I need to specify the centre and its value, that are the peak of the **1D** curve [...]" You mean 2D right?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear; I mean that in the 1D curve the centre represents the peak of the curve, that needs to be the centre of the source in 2D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Lorentz1D](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.modeling.functional_models.Lorentz1D.html#astropy.modeling.functional_models.Lorentz1D) exists, though no Lorentz2D, but you can define one following the guide for [implementing custom models](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/modeling/new-model.html#a-step-by-step-definition-of-a-1-d-gaussian-model).  Here's a basic example:

```py
from astropy.modeling import Fittable2DModel, Parameter


class Lorentz2D(Fittable2DModel):
    amplitude = Parameter()
    x_0 = Parameter()
    y_0 = Parameter()
    fwhm = Parameter

    @staticmethod
    def evaluate(x, y, amplitude, x_0, y_0, fwhm):
        hwhm = fwhm / 2.0
        return (amplitude * hwhm /
                ((x - x_0)**2 + (y - y_0)**2 + hwhm**2)**1.5)
```

I don't know if this is exactly how your 2D Lorentzian model is defined; I just adapated this definition from Wikipedia.  But you can modify this example as-needed.

Then, if you think this would be valuable to others, you might consider submitting it as a [contribution](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/development/workflow/development_workflow.html).